# What is the convention for passing in a list to a constructor and then storing it?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Let's say I have code like this:

```
    private IList<Vector3> vertices;
    private IList<uint> indices;

    public Mesh(IList<Vector3> vertices, IList<uint> indices)
    {
        // ???
    }
```

To make it clear, I want to store the vertices and indices inside it in the constructor. I've not worked very much with C# so I'm not sure how the convention looks. Am I supposed to make a copy of the entire list or can I just copy the reference? What's the convention?

Comment: I know, that's why I asked what I was supposed to do in the constructor.

Comment: Ah then I misread the question

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but I question the naming convention used here.  You should probably use different names for your constructor parameters, or find some other way of differentiating them.  For instance, I prefix all private members with an underscore; this also has the benefit of informing me of the scope of these variables whenever I see them in the code.  "There's an underscore?  Must be a private field for this instance."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the intention. Generally though, you'd want a separate copy so you can control modification of the lists inside the function. It's about encapsulation.

If that's not your intent with this class though, then it's perfectly fine to just store references to the lists.

Comment: Thanks, I realised now that it *does* depend on the intention. In my case I probably just want to make a copy. Is there no move mechanism like in C++, where if I am sure that the parameter passed in is just a temporary in the calling code, I can store the reference to it?

Comment: @JohannaOlofsson Unlike C++ you don't need to concern yourself with whether or not the reference will be "valid"; it will be valid for as long as you hold onto it, precicely *because* you're holding onto it.  The question is whether you want changes to the list via your reference to also be reflected in uses of the reference by the caller, and vice versa.  If you *want* those semantics, copy the reference, if you don't want those semantics, make a copy of the list itself.

Comment: I didn't really ask anything concerning the validity of the reference. What I was wondering was if there's any way to know that you're the only one holding on to a reference. That would make you able to just copy the reference without worrying about anything else affecting the list.

Comment: @JohannaOlofsson You *know* that someone else has a reference to the list.  At least the caller of this method does.  The only way to know that nobody else has a reference to the list is to create it yourself and never pass it anywhere else.  There is no way for the code to know if the other holders of the reference will mutate the list, although you, as a developer, may (or may not) know that.

Comment: Well in C++ you can make a special method overload that gets called instead when the parameter is temporary (isn't stored after the call by the caller). But I guess that's not possible in C#. And maybe I shouldn't care about such low-level things anyway when using C#.

Answer (score 4):

You can just copy the *reference* to the list.
Since you gave your member variables and your constructor arguments the same name, you'd have to use the `this` keyword.

```
private IList<Vector3> vertices;
private IList<uint> indices;

public Mesh(IList<Vector3> vertices, IList<uint> indices)
{
    this.vertices = vertices;
    this.indices = indices;
}
```

The lists will now be stored in your Mesh class

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you need. You can simply write

```
this.vertices = vertices;
```

This will store a reference to the list. This means, every change made outside will reflect in your list;

On the other hand you can copy the list -

```
this.vertices = new List<Vector3>(vertices);
```

This will actually copy the items in the list and you will not see changes made outside. Note - the copied items will still be references. Any changes made to them will reflect inside your method. If you wish, you can make a copy of them as well for your new list.

Again - it depends on what you need.

Comment: The specific question is whether he should copy the list, or just copy the reference, not *how* to do either.  This doesn't answer that question.

Comment: "whether **she** should copy the list"

Comment: @Servy There is no correct answer for "should". To understand what "should" be done, one needs to understand the different options and their impact. This is what I have written in my answer. The syntax was added for completeness.

Comment: @Vadim I agree, there is no one right or wrong answer.  It does depend, but just saying "It depends" along is a pretty poor answer.  What does it depend on?  What factors should you consider, etc?  Or perhaps you could ask some clarifying questions of the OP to help you figure out enough information to give a real answer.

Comment: @Servy, this looks as if we're looking at 2 different answers. I clearly state the impact of each option (AKA "factors you consider"), I even make a note that the items themselves may need copying. Only then I say - depends on what you need. How is it "just saying it depends".

Answer (score 0):

```
private IList<Vector3> vertices;
private IList<uint> indices;

public Mesh(IList<Vector3> vertices, IList<uint> indices)
{
    this.vertices = vertices;
    this.indices = indices;
}
```

If you want to access it within `Mesh`, then yes, you'll need to put them in there. This is usually done as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should always be careful with these kinds of things. For instance, if your Mesh class is meant to be immutable, then you should make a copy of the data to prevent some outside code from altering what's intended to be uneditable data.

Personally, unless I have good reasons to do otherwise, I always store a copy of the data.